# Why doesn't my view update ObservedObject inside a different View in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, observable, observedobject

My `ObservedObject` will not connect with another view.

I have:

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var destination: String = ""
    @Published var arrivalTime = Date()
    @Published var isLoading: Bool = false
    @Published var cleanedTafString: String = ""
}
```

which declares the objects to be updated.

My main view, where I make the connection with my `AppState()` class, once the button "GO" is pressed, the `func LoadingProcess()` is executed which is inside of a `Task`, runs an `async` function `runAllFunctions()` in a seperate swift file. Once That is complete, `$readyToNavigate` (@State private var) triggers `.navigationDestination`to change `View` to `ResultsScreenView()`:

```
struct InitialScreenView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var app = AppState()
    @State private var currentTimeDate = Date.now
    @State private var readyToNavigate : Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Text(DateFormatterView.currentLocalDateFormatted())
                        }
                        .padding(2)
                        Text(DateFormatterView.currentGMTDateFormatted())
                    }
                    HStack {
                        TextFieldView(preFill: "Destination", fill: $app.destination)
                    }
                    Button(action: LoadingProcess, label: {
                        Text("GO")
                    })
                        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $readyToNavigate) {
                            ResultsScreenView()}
                        .navigationTitle("WxStrip")
                }
                if app.isLoading {
                    LoadingView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    func LoadingProcess() {
        Task {
            app.isLoading = true
            let resultString = await app.runAllFunctions()
            app.isLoading = false
            // Update the observed object and trigger a refresh of the view
            app.cleanedTafString = resultString
            app.objectWillChange.send()
            readyToNavigate = true
            print(app.cleanedTafString)
        }
    }
}
```

Once the `runAllFunctions()` function has finished inside the `Task`, I am telling `app.cleanedTafString` to update with the string that is returned from `runAllFunctions()`.

This works fine for the current view if I wanted to display it in `InitialScreenView`, but I don't. I need it on a separate `View` called `ResultsScreenView`.

```
struct ResultsScreenView: View {

    @ObservedObject private var app = AppState()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button("Push me", action: {
                DisplayCleaned()
            })
        }
    }
    func DisplayCleaned() {
        print("Printout \(app.cleanedTafString)")
    }
}
```

Ideally I want to display the string in a `Text()` on screen but for troubleshooting have just called a function on press of the button....

This returns an empty string every time. It doesn't matter which of the `@Published var` I try to print out, it just doesn't link somehow.

What is weird is that, on the initial declaration of the `@Published var` if I enter some text instead of an empty string, it will print that instead of nothing. It's as though `ResultsScreenView` is only ever looking at the initial declaration of the `@Published var` and not seeing the updates. Although I know for sure they update as I can display it in print statements and in `Text()` fields on screen in the `InitialScreenView`....

Comment: You should have only one source of truth declared as `@StateObject private var app = AppState()`
 in your view hierarchy, that you then pass onto the other views. Currently,
 you have multiple `@ObservedObject private var app = AppState()` that have no relations
 to each other.
 
 Have a look at this  **official** link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app:  [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app)

Comment: In SwiftUI its `.task` not `Task {}`, e.g. `.task(id: app.isLoading)` {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for working with `ObservableObject`, you must first declare your object with the `@StateObject` property wrapper. It would initialize your object once and for all, and keep its state in memory even if the SwiftUI view refresh.

Then, if you need to pass its state through child view, we will declare it as a `@ObservedObject`, but do not initialize it the way you did it in `ResultsScreenView`.

```swift
struct InitialScreenView: View {

  @StateObject private var app = AppState()

  // Rest of your code
}

struct ResultsScreenView: View {

  @ObservedObject var app: AppState

  // Rest of your code
}
```

You will have to pass your object through the `ResultsScreenView` initializer:

```swift
ResultsScreenView(app: app)
```

As a reminder, it works the same way as `@State` and `@Binding`, but for objects.

Comment: In your example, `ResultsScreenView(app:)` will be unavailable, because `app` is `private`. You need to either declare the initialiser explicitly or remove the `private` access modifier from `app`.

Comment: My bad. Yes, do not declare your `@ObservedObject` private. I made the change.